# Sephadex column for alpha-amylase

Tags: proteins, enzymes, purification, chromatography

I want to purify crude alpha-amylase with column chromatography. I am using a spehadex 75, But for some reason I can't find any information on how to make the slurry.

I can quickly find tons of information on how to pack and store a column, but what i really want to know is how much powder and buffer do I mix together?

Answer (score 3):

The '75' of Sephadex G-75 refers to the **water regain value**, which is defined as the grams of water absorbed upon hydration of 1g dry powder, multiplied by 10 (see [Reiland](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0075753508703334)). Thus the water-regain value of Sephadex G-75 is about 7.5ml. This value refers only to the water contained 
within the gel particles and *not* to the water trapped outside of the particles in a packed gel ([Reiland](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0075753508703334)). As a rule-of-thumb, the latter figure can be estimated to 50%.

So ... 1g of dry Sephadex will give about 15 ml of packed gel

From [here](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/g75120?lang=en&region=IE&gclid=Cj0KEQjwofHHBRDS0Pnhpef89ucBEiQASEp6LOutCIWbfrywSQ7DzLLDX00NqCA2kErDrFUhRqChJAYaAv9c8P8HAQ): *1 g swells to 12-15 mL gel*

Just a thought ...
Does alpha-amylase interact with Sephadex?  Maybe 'thinking' it resembles a substrate, and (reversibly) binding to it or otherwise interacting to cause effects in addition to gel-filtration ?